# Nerddinner delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

I'm pretty new to MVC and I'm looking at the code of NerdDinner

View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<NerdDinner.Models.Dinner>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Delete Confirmation: <%:Model.Title %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>
        Delete Confirmation
    </h2>

    <div>
        <p>Please confirm you want to cancel the dinner titled: 
        <i> <%:Model.Title %>? </i> </p>
    </div>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

        <input name="confirmButton" type="submit" value="Delete" />        

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost, Authorize]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, string confirmButton) {

        Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);

        if (dinner == null)
            return View("NotFound");

        if (!dinner.IsHostedBy(User.Identity.Name))
            return View("InvalidOwner");

        dinnerRepository.Delete(dinner);
        dinnerRepository.Save();

        return View("Deleted");
    }
```

How does the controller get the ID of the item to delete? It seems like nothing on the view is containing the ID to be passed to the controller.

Comment: look at nerddinner with razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`using (Html.BeginForm())` will render an HTML `<form>` element whose `action` attribute is by default the current URI.

That means that if you are currently at `/Dinner/Delete/5`, the form will post to that URI and the regular model binding will come into play, mapping the `5` to the `{id}` route parameter.